# IIS Maximum Worker Process spins only two while max is set to four

Tags: iis, application-pools, iis-8

I've set my Application pool to `Start Mode = AlwaysRunning` and the `Maximum Worker Processes = 4`. And I've set `Preload Enabled = True` on the website. After recycling the AppPool only two workers spin up while I've asked for four.

Any idea why and how to get it to spin up to four?

Answer (score 1):

Preload only means IIS will detect which applications are specified for a recently spawned worker and build an URL to access them, so it goes through the IIS processing pipeline. More about it [here](http://blogs.iis.net/wadeh/archive/2012/05/01/application-initialization-part-2.aspx).

AFAIK, there is no process to enforce a minimum worker count at IIS level, like in Apache.

You may take a look at adjusting the [CLR thread throttling settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/perfworld/archive/2010/01/13/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-asp-net-by-adjusting-the-clr-thread-throttling-properties.aspx) though, but I've no direct experience yet with this.